# Communicate a *feeling* of impossibility

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

I need a word or phrase that communicates the feeling of impossibility without communicating a literal impossibility. Example:

> Due to the incessant noise sleep was impossible

It is not *truly* impossible. It just felt that way due to the mood of the character.

How could I better phrase this to communicate that it felt impossible without saying it was truly impossible?

Comment: Sleep was "beyond reach".

Comment: Or, "getting any sleep was hopeless".

Comment: *Due to the incessant noise sleep* ***seemed*** *impossible.* (Or *seemed hopeless*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the incessant noise, sleep was futile.

Futile: "incapable of producing any useful result; pointless."

https://www.google.gr/?ion=1&espv=2#q=futile+definition+

Answer (score 0):

*improbable, unlikely, doubtful, a remote chance*